# What is this mode of convergence called?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

$\|f_k\|_p\to \|f\|_p$: Is there a name for this type of convergence?

What I know is convergence in $L^p$ norm usually means $\|f-f_k\|_p\to 0$, which is different from the above.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, in $\Bbb R^2$, the two sequences $(1-\frac1n, 0)$ and $(\cos n, \sin n)$ "converge" to $(0,1)$ in this sense. Does that really signify anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is really convergence in any reasonable sense, it's just saying the two of them are on the same radius sphere, so if I were to call it anything, I'd say it's convergence as a sequence of real numbers, i.e. if $a_k=\lVert f_k\rVert_p\in\Bbb R$ then $a_k\to a=\lVert f\rVert_p\in\Bbb R$.